# how do I use MATLAB for-loop iteration to create MySQL tables?

Tags: mysql, matlab

My MATLAB string variable is

`list ={'table1','table2'...`}

and I want to create these tables in MYSQL with the code below which is failing;

```
handle=list;
size_h = max(size(handle));
for i = size_h
    e = 'create table handle(i) (col int(11))';
    curs=exec(conn,e);
end
```

I know that the trouble is where I have used my `handle(i)` in my query, becuase removing that and using a simple table name works as normal.

How would I use my `'i'` to create the specific tables?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is you are not passing the actual table names to your connection string, you are rather passing literally `handle(i)`. One alternative is to build the string manually or use the [`sprintf`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/sprintf.html) function. Also `handle` is a cell and to access it's contents you should use `{}` instead of `()`. I also changed the counter from `i` which stands for the built-in imaginary unit in matlab to `ii`.

```
handle=list;
size_h = max(size(handle));
for ii = 1:size_h
    e = sprintf('create table %s (col int(11))',handle{ii});
    curs=exec(conn,e);
end
```

Comment: thanks @brodoll, I also had a look at the `sprintf` function to see what it's all about.